# Throw exception from Guava EventBus subscriber

Tags: java, jpa, guava, event-bus

I am using Guava EventBus in sync. How can I rollback the complete transaction if any of the subscribers throw an Exception? How can I throw an Exception which will not be caught by the EventBus Subscriber?

Comment: I'd be kind of surprised if either of these were possible.

Comment: if these are not possible, isn't this a limitation of event bus that it cannot be transactional?

Comment: What do you mean by `transaction`. Do you mean JPA Transaction?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `java.lang.ThreadLocal` variable across the publisher and the subscriber.

Publisher needs to be wrapped in a class which reads thread local exception and throws it

```
public void publish(Event event) {
  eventBus.post(event);
  if(threadLocalException != null) {
    Store threadLocalException in some variable say e
    Clear threadLocalException variable
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Subscriber needs to be wrapped in a class to set the exception in thread local variable

```
public abstract class EventSubscriber<T extends Event> {

  @Subscribe
  public void invoke(T event) {
    try {
      handle(event);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Set thread local variable to e
    }
  }

  protected abstract void handle(T event);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to look at the source code of Guava's `EventBus` class.

Let's start from the end:

> How can I throw an Exception which will not be caught by the EventBus Subscriber?

Subscribers' methods are called in sequence, one after another, by `com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher#dispatch` method. To call methods of your Subscribers, EventBus use reflection's method `Method#invoke` which, in turn, throws `InvocationTargetException` if called method throws an exception.

As you can also see, `InvocationTargetException` (which will be wrapped around your `Exception`) is handled as follows:

```
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  if (e.getCause() instanceof Error) {
    throw (Error) e.getCause();
  }
  throw e;
}
```

at the upper level, exception is handled like that:

```
try {
  invokeSubscriberMethod(event);
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  bus.handleSubscriberException(e.getCause(), context(event));
}
```

**TL;DR**

So, the only way to omit `EventBus` exception handler is to throw not `Exception`, but `Error` in your subscribing method - what is certainly a bad practise.

> How can I rollback the complete transaction if any of the subscribers throw an Exception?

`EventBus` exception handler handles exceptions by calling `com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus#handleSubscriberException` method. It looks like this:

```
try {
  exceptionHandler.handleException(e, context);
} catch (Throwable e2) {
  // logging
}
```

So, any exceptions thrown from exception handler will not help. You have two choices:

1. Either throw Error from your subscriber method (it's sooo bad)
2. Or manually set transaction as rollback-only from any place in this flow. I think that the best place for such things is obviously `EventBus` exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit EventBus and make your own eventBus which will throw exception.
The package must be com.google.common.eventbus for handleSubscriberException is an internal method.

```
package com.google.common.eventbus;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;

/**
 * A eventbus wihch will throw exceptions during event handle process.
 * @author ytm
 *
 */
public class ErrorThrowEventBus extends EventBus {

    /**
     * Creates a new EventBus with the given {@code identifier}.
     *
     * @param identifier a brief name for this bus, for logging purposes. Should be a valid Java
     *     identifier.
     */
    public ErrorThrowEventBus(String identifier) {
        super(
            identifier,
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor(),
            Dispatcher.perThreadDispatchQueue(),
            LoggingHandler.INSTANCE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new EventBus with the given {@link SubscriberExceptionHandler}.
     *
     * @param exceptionHandler Handler for subscriber exceptions.
     * @since 16.0
     */
    public ErrorThrowEventBus(SubscriberExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
        super(
            "default",
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor(),
            Dispatcher.perThreadDispatchQueue(),
            exceptionHandler);
    }

    /**
     * Just throw a EventHandleException if there's any exception.
     * @param e
     * @param context
     * @throws EventHandleException 
     */
    @Override
    void handleSubscriberException(Throwable e, SubscriberExceptionContext context) throws EventHandleException {
        throw new EventHandleException(e);
    }
}
```